# Sorting an ObservableCollection<object> doesn't update the UI

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, windows-runtime

I'm building a Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRt) app.

I have an `ObservableCollection<object>`, i need to add, modify and sort the items of this collection.

when I add an item to this list everything is ok, if i cast one of this object in the list and i edit the property of the object the `INotifyPropertyChanged` takes care of updating the ui.

but when i sort the list the UI doesn't respect the order of the list.

the only way to update the UI is to use `Move()`, but as i have found this method is veri resource hungry.

I have tried with LINQ, but as a result the list is ordered, but the element in the UI remain in the same order.

there is any alternative way to sort this list?

this is some code insede my ViewModel

```
ActiveServices = ActiveServices.Where(x => x is ActiveServiceControlData).OrderByDescending(x => (x as ActiveServiceControlData).NotificationNumber).ToObservableCollection();


private static ObservableCollection<object> activeServices;
public ObservableCollection<object> ActiveServices
{
    get { return activeServices; }
    set
    {
        activeServices = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ActiveServices);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

My big issue is that in the ObservableCollection there are different types of object, i use this collection as a ItemsSource for a ListView with an ItemTemplateSelector based on the type of the object inside the ObservableCollection, and i need to sort only the element of a specific type.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is for notifying a subscriber about changes to an object's properties. An `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which notifies subscribers of changes to the contents of a collection.

Comment: LINQ methods typically do not have side-effects. Show us what you've tried to do (ie. provide code) and we can see if we can show you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: You have a rather unusual RaisePropertyChanged() method there, can I see the implementation of it?

Comment: i'm using mvvmlight this is why it looks different

Comment: I see nothing off the top of my head that would make that not work. It could be simplified slightly, but... the NPC should propagate and tell the UI to re-read the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to sort `ObservableCollection` is to extend base `ObservableCollection` and make use of internal `CollectionChanged` events.

Your current code recreates whole collection which is inefficient (and your user interface may "blink").

```
public class SortableObservableCollection<T, TSortKey> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, TKey> _sortByKey;

    public SortableObservableCollection(Func<T, TKey> sortByKey)
    {
        _sortByKey = sortByKey;
    }


    public void Sort() {
         // slow O(n^2) sort but should be good enough because user interface rarely has milion of items
        var sortedList = Items.OrderBy(_sortByKey).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.Count; ++i)
        {
            var actualItemIndex = Items.IndexOf(sortedList[i]);

            if (actualItemIndex != i)
                Move(actualItemIndex, i);
        }

    }
}
```

.. and then just call .Sort();

The above method has big advantage over recreating whole item source - your user interface can react to that in pretty way (animation of item move instead of recreate "blink")

Comment: With this code the app goes in crash due to different types of object inside the observablecollection

Comment: @frenk91 exception please

Comment: It was a xaml exception caused by the incremental update behaviour, not your code. But the ui is not refreshing anyway after the sorting. But as i have explained the move() method works fine

Comment: @frenk91 with sorting without Move? UI must refresh - there is not other way, you might not see that in UI (doubtly but possible) but there is heavy UI perfomance impact (which is negliable in case of small lists though)